# Passing value from vbscript to batch file is not working correctly

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have written a batch file that runs a vbscript and then collects the values from the vbscrit for further process.

This is my code:

**myBatch.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM ECHO ============= RUNNING BATCH =============
ECHO. 

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('CSCRIPT C:\myVBScript.vbs') do (
    ECHO RESULT: %%a
   )


REM ECHO ============= FINNISHED BATCH =============
ECHO.
```

**myVBScript.vbs**

```
    Option Explicit
Dim values, splitStr


    'ask for value
    values=InputBox("Please provide a list separated by semicolon","Do stuff","item1;item2") 
    splitStr=Split(values,";")

    If UBound(splitStr) >= 1 Then
        WScript.Echo splitStr(0)
        WScript.Echo splitStr(1)
    End If
```

**And this is the output:**

RESULT: Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8

RESULT: Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

RESULT: item1

RESULT: item2

Where does the two first lines come from and how can I avoid them? This is very annoing and I cant figure out how to just get the actual values (item1 and item2).

Comment: General question, why would you want to use batch script to process the output from VBScript? Given that batch is *distinctly* less capable than VBScript in this department you should consider using VBScript all the way.

Comment: Becuase this is deep down inside an existing application, and since I opened a batch file and vbscript for the frist time yesterday I do not feel confident to make major changes in the existing project.

Comment: Fair enough. But if you spend time studying how to do certain things, keep in mind that given the choice between batch and VBS, that time is better spent on studying VBS.

Comment: The other (less recommendable) answer would have been to use the `skip` paramter to `for`, like in `for /F "skip=2 delims=" %%a in ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two lines

> Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

are a banner that is automatically printed by the interpreter `cscript.exe`.

Use the `nologo` parameter

```
cscript //nologo C:\myVBScript.vbs
```

to avoid the banner in the script's output.

You can also make `nologo` the default for your user by running the following command once:

```
cscript //nologo //s
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew the answer should be simple

Comment: @Ansger: What are the doubles slashes for?

Comment: @Tomalak Parameters with single slashes are passed to the script. Parameters for the interpreter have double slashes. See `cscript //?`.

Comment: @Ansgar Single slashes have always worked (and continue to work) very well for me. I usually give the parameters to cscript *before* and the parameters to the script after the the script name.

Comment: @Tomalak Hmm... it seems double slashes are indeed optional when you pass the interpreter arguments before the script. I never bothered checking before.

Comment: Well, in any case double slashes are what the current `cscript.exe /?` help screen suggests. I never bothered to check *that* recently. It didn't use to be that way in earlier versions of cscript, IIRC.

Comment: That you misremember. The command help has shown double slashes since at least Windows 2000.

Comment: Okay, then I can only attribute it to selective perception. ;)